# AVPlayer status always AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avplayer

I am using AVPlayer to play audio from a URL

In ViewDidLoad:

```
self.playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageText]];

self.player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem];

[player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:0 context:nil];

[player play];
```

**Observer**

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object
                        change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
    if (object == player && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
        if (player.status == AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay) {
            //[playingLbl setText:@"Playing Audio"];
            NSLog(@"fineee");
            [playBtn setEnabled:YES];
        } else if (player.status == AVPlayerStatusFailed) {
            // something went wrong. player.error should contain some information
            NSLog(@"not fineee");
            NSLog(@"%@",player.error);

        }
        else if (player.status == AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown) {
            NSLog(@"AVPlayer Unknown");


        }
    }
}
```

but the player sometimes is stuck and does not play the audio but then also status is AVPlayerStatusReadyToPlay. It never goes inside AVPlayerStatusFailed or  AVPlayerItemStatusUnknown. As i want to handle AVPlayer's error, it must go inside these as well. Please help!!

Answer (score 33):

You should observe CurrentItem's status. AVPlayer failed because of AVPlayerItem failed, if anythings went wrong, it begins from AVPlayerItem then AVPlayer.

try:

```
[item addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

in your observeValueForKeyPath:

```
if (object == audioPlayer.currentItem && [keyPath isEqualToString:@"status"]) {
    if (audioPlayer.currentItem.status == AVPlayerItemStatusFailed) {
        NSLog(@"------player item failed:%@",audioPlayer.currentItem.error);
    }
}
```

You can take a look of AVPlayer's handling or use it directly from [HysteriaPlayer](https://github.com/StreetVoice/HysteriaPlayer), my open source project.

Comment: unfortunately not helping me. if i play an item and turn off the internet, the music stops, but no event fired

Comment: I added this solution for internet turn off scenario. If first time i played song and turned off internet then getting failure response pause the song. Again played same song and turned off internet in this case i did not get the failure response. Can you please suggest how to handle this scenario. @DavidSeek did you find any solution for this?

Comment: Did someone get solution to play media automatically when turning off internet gives failure response and pause the song.